# What is the scope of the query without setting the query parameters and only setting the query field in dfuse Search?

Tags: dfuse

`q=account:eosio.token action:transfer&sort=desc`

I restricted the action to transfer, but there are some transactions in the result that are not transfer. What is the reason?

---

`q=receiver:eosio.token action:transfer data.from:eosbetcrash1 data.to:eosbetbank11&sort=desc`

I want to implement the basic transaction query now. For example, I wrote this. According to my understanding, I should receive the transaction of eosbetcrash1 to eosbetbank11, but the data actually received is not that

Before I queried some parameters, I couldn't find the reason for the result shown. I found it because I didn't add sort=desc, but why can't I find the result in ascending order? Can I find the result by doing descending search? So this is still back to the beginning of the question, in the case of not setting start_block, block_count and other parameters, what is the default query scope?

Comment: There's no parameter for 'sort' in dfuse SQE. Are you using some third-party-lib ?

Comment: There is a `sort` parameter: `https://docs.dfuse.io/#rest-api-get-v0-search-transactions` which in fact is misleading as it indicates in which direction to search either forward (from start block X and higher) or backward (from start block X and lower).

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, `block_count` has a default value of around 1000000. If you want to search everything, do pass a huge block_count that covers the full chain history.